# Button returns correct values, but is not displayed to the screen once I press it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing this fullstack course to learn about web dev: https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/getting_data_from_server

And I have a problem with section 2.13*.

I am able to display a list of the countries after filtering with the button. Pressing the button returns the correct values from the countries arrays as seen with the console.log(country), but it doesn't to the screen.

My guess is that I can't return a div item within another item, but I am pretty sure that works in normal cases, so the fact that I'm returning the item to a different return statement might be the issue?

How can I fix this? I know my code is messy and a refactor might make things simpler, but it is currently beyond me right now since I find it easier to refactor working code.

In the DisplayCountries component, I've tried apply a map to countries that fit the filter input and prints it into a div item. Now when I add a button beside it, it displays correctly, but pressing it does not yield what I expect.

Is the correct approach here to use a useState with the button, so that each button click will rerender the screen? How would I go about doing this if so?

After pressing the button, the detailed information of the country should display such as in 2.12* from the linked website.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

//feed array of countries
const printLanguages = (languages) => {
  // console.log('map', languages.map(language => language.name))
  return languages.map(language => <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)
}

const displayCountryView = (country) => {
  console.log(country)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{country.name}</h1>
      <p>capital {country.capital}</p>
      <p>population {country.population}</p>

      <h2>languages</h2>
      <ul>
        {printLanguages(country.languages)}
      </ul>
      <img src={country.flag} height="100" width="100"></img>

    </div>

  )
}

const DisplayCountries = ({ countries, searchValue }) => {
  const displayFilter = filteredCountries(countries, searchValue)
  // console.log('current search', searchValue)
  if (displayFilter.length >= 10) {
    return <p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>
  } else if (isFiltered(searchValue)) {
      if (displayFilter.length > 1 && displayFilter.length < 10) {
        console.log('new level')
        return displayFilter.map(country => <div key={country.name}>{country.name}{showButton(country)}</div>)
      } else if (displayFilter.length === 1) {
        // console.log('suh')
        // return displayFilter.map(country => <p key={country.name}>{country.name}</p>)
        const country = displayFilter
        return displayCountryView(country[0])
        // console.log(country)
        // console.log('country.name', country[0])
        // console.log(country[0].languages)
        // console.log(printLanguages(country[0].languages))
        // return (
        //   <div>
        //     <h1>{country[0].name}</h1>
        //     <p>capital {country[0].capital}</p>
        //     <p>population {country[0].population}</p>

        //     <h2>languages</h2>
        //     <ul>
        //       {printLanguages(country[0].languages)}
        //     </ul>
        //     <img src={country[0].flag} height="100" width="100"></img>
        //   </div>

        // )
      }
  } else {
    return <p>empty</p>
  }
}

const showButton = (country) => {
  return <button type="button" onClick={() => displayCountryView(country)}>show</button>
}

const filteredCountries = (countries, searchValue) => {
  const showCountries = (!isFiltered(searchValue))
    ? [{ name: "hi" }]
    : countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
  // const countryMap = countries.map(country => country.name.toLowerCase())
  // console.log(countryMap)
  // return countryMap
  return showCountries
}

function isFiltered(value) {
  if (value === '') {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}

const Filter = ({ search, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <form >
      <div>
        find countries <input value={search} onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  const [search, setNewSearch] = useState('')
  const [showCountry, setShowCountry] = useState('false')

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('effect')
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => {
        // console.log('promise fulfilled')
        setCountries(response.data)
      })
  }, [])

  // const countryNames = countries.map(country => country.name)
  // console.log('name', countryNames)

  const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    setNewSearch(event.target.value)
  }

  // const fil = countries.filter(country => country.name==='Afg')
  // console.log(countries[0])
  // console.log('filtered:',fil)
  // console.log(countries[0])
  // console.log('render', countries.length, 'persons')

  return (
    <div>
      <Filter search={search} onChange={handleSearchChange} />
      <form>
        <div>
          <DisplayCountries countries={countries} searchValue={search} />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: hey there, Please post minimal code to reproduce issue, or you can share fiddle link.

Comment: I think when you click the button, it just returns the html code but your program doesn't know what to do with it. Don't know where to put it in the dom. You could have returned anything and it will not show up in the dom.